# New Zend_Db_Table_Row based on MSSQL table with a PK uniqueidentifier - Cannot refresh row as parent is missing

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, zend-framework, pdo

I've got an existing MSSQL table that has a primary key of type `uniqueidentifier` and default value of `NEWID()`.

I can't seem to get Zend Framework's (1.1.11) `Zend_Db_Table_Row` object to properly create a new row in this table via `save()`, it gives the error `'Cannot refresh row as parent is missing'` (though the row is actually inserted correctly).

Looking at `Zend_Db_Table_Row_Abstract` the error comes from the `_refresh()` function and throws an exception because it can't fetch the inserted row back.  The `$where` value in the `_refresh()` function shows the primary key value is `''` and thus can't match the new row.

Is there some issue with Zend figuring out what the value of the primary key is after an insert if its a `uniqueidentifier` column?

Answer (score 0):

My solution at the moment is to simply run a separate query to generate a `uniqueidentifier`, and assign this to the primary key field before saving it, e.g.

```
public function getNewId()
{
    $result = $this->getAdapter()->query('SELECT NEWID()')->fetch();

    return $result['computed'];
}
```

Then assign it and save:

```
$row = $tblWhatever->createrow($data);
$row->primaryKeyName = $tblWhatever->getNewId(); 
$row->save();
```

It's not as clean as having Zend pick up the PK generated value from the column's default value entry, but it saves without throwing exceptions.